# How to find continuous repeated values in column

Tags: r

Hi I have a df which contains "var" and "value" column, how to find/calculate output "column" grouped by var if the values appear >2 times in value column

```
var = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
value = c(22,1,1,1,1,31,21,1,1,1)
df = data.frame(var, value)

output = c("non_rep","non_rep","non_rep","rep","rep","non_rep","non_rep","non_rep","rep")
```

Expected output:

```
var value   output
A   21  non_rep
A   1   non_rep
A   1   non_rep
A   1   rep
A   1   rep
B   31  non_rep
B   21  non_rep
B   1   non_rep
B   1   non_rep
B   1   rep
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can (var, value) groups appear multiple times? Like another (A, 1) group after (B, 1) that needs to be treated separately? I was working on an answer assuming that but it may be overly complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr` solution which seems to work at least on your example data:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(var, value) %>% 
  mutate(output = ifelse(lag(value, n = 2) != value | is.na(lag(value, n = 2)),
                         "non_rep", "rep")) %>%
  ungroup()


# A tibble: 10 x 3
     var value  output
   <chr> <dbl>   <chr>
 1     A    22 non_rep
 2     A     1 non_rep
 3     A     1 non_rep
 4     A     1     rep
 5     A     1     rep
 6     B    31 non_rep
 7     B    21 non_rep
 8     B     1 non_rep
 9     B     1 non_rep
10     B     1     rep
```

Answer (score 5):

Group by both columns, and then label all values after the first 2 as `"rep"`:

```
df$output <- ifelse(ave(df$value, df[c("var","value")], FUN=seq_along) > 2, "rep", "non_rep")

#   var value  output
#1    A    22 non_rep
#2    A     1 non_rep
#3    A     1 non_rep
#4    A     1     rep
#5    A     1     rep
#6    B    31 non_rep
#7    B    21 non_rep
#8    B     1 non_rep
#9    B     1 non_rep
#10   B     1     rep
```

A `dplyr` translation might be:

```
df %>%
  group_by(var,value) %>%
  mutate(output = case_when(row_number() > 2 ~ "rep", TRUE ~ "non_rep") )
```

Answer (score 3):

If `(var, value)` pairs can occur multiple times and need to be treated as separate groups, you can use `data.table`'s `rleid` function to do the grouping:

```
var = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B", "A", "A", "A")
value =c(22,1,1,1,1,31,21,1,1,1, 22, 22, 22)
df = data.frame( var,value)

df$group = data.table::rleid(df$var, df$value)

df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(output = ifelse(row_number() > 2, "rep", "non_rep"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   group [6]
      var value group  output
   <fctr> <dbl> <int>   <chr>
 1      A    22     1 non_rep
 2      A     1     2 non_rep
 3      A     1     2 non_rep
 4      A     1     2     rep
 5      A     1     2     rep
 6      B    31     3 non_rep
 7      B    21     4 non_rep
 8      B     1     5 non_rep
 9      B     1     5 non_rep
10      B     1     5     rep
11      A    22     6 non_rep
12      A    22     6 non_rep
13      A    22     6     rep
```

Comment: How to exclude continuous NA's from value column , i.e if the value contains NA values can we exclude them in output.

Comment: i mean if NA available can we add 'Not_available'' in output column

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  output := if(.N > 2) rep(c("non_rep", "rep"), 
         c(2, .N-2)) else "non_rep" , .(var, value)]
df
#    var value  output
# 1:   A    22 non_rep
# 2:   A     1 non_rep
# 3:   A     1 non_rep
# 4:   A     1     rep
# 5:   A     1     rep
# 6:   B    31 non_rep
# 7:   B    21 non_rep
# 8:   B     1 non_rep
# 9:   B     1 non_rep
#10:   B     1     rep
```